# Using Grails taglibs inside GSPs

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, taglib

**Please note:** Even though I'm using the [Grails-Shiro](http://grails.org/plugin/shiro) plugin here, this is a pure Grails taglib question, so should be answerable by anybody who is familiar with Grails taglibs and GSPs, regardless of their experience with this particular plugin.

---

Grails 2.4.5 here. I'd like to use some tags inside my GSP to determine if the authenticated user has a permission (string) with a value of `'app_admin'`. Something like:

```
<g:if test="${authenticated_user_has_permission('app_admin')}">
    <!-- A bunch of HTML here, but only for admins! -->
</g:if>
```

This Grails-Shiro plugin defines a [`hasPermission`](https://github.com/pledbrook/grails-shiro/blob/master/shiro2/grails-app/taglib/org/apache/shiro/grails/ShiroTagLib.groovy#L241) tag that I think I could use, but not sure how. My attempt at:

```
<g:if test="${shiro.hasPermission('app_admin')}">
    <!-- A bunch of HTML here, but only for admins! -->
</g:if>
```

...failed miserably. Any ideas how I could use this plugin-provided tag as part of my permission check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never used shiro, but common sense tells me to use something like:

```
<shiro:hasPermission permission="app_admin">
  ....
</shiro:hasPermission>
```

you can not use `<g:if>` here, as shiro tags do not return anything